# Selenium dropdown menu click with span element in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select ISO time as an option in a dropdown menu with Selenium and Python:

[This is the html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHDi1.png),

[with UNIX selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMGak.png),

[and with ISO selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2oRY.png)

This is my code:

```py
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select , WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
browser = Edge(executable_path=path_to_webdriver, options=options)
browser.get('the page I want to scrape')

#[...other parts of the code...]

#click on the dropdown menu arrow and it opens it
Menu_Arrow_Down = '/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/span/span[2]'
open_menu = browser.find_element_by_xpath(Menu_Arrow_Down)
open_menu.click()
time.sleep(3)

#trying to select the 'ISO time' format with a click, but doesn't work
Select_ISO_Time = '/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/span/span[1]/span/span'
ISO_option = browser.find_element_by_xpath(Select_ISO_Time)
ISO_option.click()

#these are all full XPaths:
Timeformat_select_container = '/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/span'
Inner_slot = '/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/span/span[1]'
Button_children = '/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/span/span[1]/span'
ISO_time_span = '/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/span/span[1]/span/span'
```

What am I doing wrong? I've also tried with the Select method but it seems it doesn't apply to span dropdown menus!

This is the HTML code:

```html
<span id="time-format-select" role="button" class="container-WDZ0PRNh intent-default-WDZ0PRNh border-thin-WDZ0PRNh size-medium-WDZ0PRNh adjust-position-WDZ0PRNh first-row-WDZ0PRNh first-col-WDZ0PRNh button-tFul0OhX dropdown-NQ10filh" tabindex="0" data-role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-labelledby="time-format-select">
    <span class="inner-slot-W53jtLjw inner-middle-slot-W53jtLjw">
        <span class="button-children-tFul0OhX">
            <span>ISO time</span>
        </span>
    </span>
<span class="inner-slot-W53jtLjw interactive-W53jtLjw">
    <span class="button-fy1qDthb">
        <span class="icon-fy1qDthb">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 11 7" width="11" height="7" fill="none">
                <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.3" d="M.5 1.5l5 4 5-4"></path>
            </svg>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
    <span class="highlight-WDZ0PRNh"></span>
</span>
```

and this is the URL to the page: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/BlxZCwOJ/?symbol=CBOT%3AZQJ2023
the menu appears by clicking on the down-pointing arrow next to the Unnamed element on the top-right corner of the screen, and then on the export chart option.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML in the form of text rather than image? Also, share the URL of the application if it can be shared to public.

Answer (score -1):

After clicking on the dropdown menu, use the below code:

```
action = ActionChains(browser)
action.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP).perform()
time.sleep(2)
action.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
time.sleep(2)
action.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
time.sleep(2)
action.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
time.sleep(2)
action.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains, Keys
```

**Explanation:** As the element cannot be located and performed action against, we can use selenium's `ActionChains` class to perform keyboard strokes. In the code above, after the dropdown is clicked, it will click on <kbd>up arrow</kbd> first, then presses <kbd>TAB</kbd> 4 times, resulting in selection of the required dropdown menu "ISO time"

**Result:**

[image]

**SUGGESTIONS:** Avoid using absolute XPATH where ever possible. Instead use other locators like ID, NAME etc. or use relative XPATH expressions.
For example, you can change the below code:

```
Menu_Arrow_Down = '/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/span/span[2]'
open_menu = browser.find_element_by_xpath(Menu_Arrow_Down)
open_menu.click()
```

To:

```
open_menu = browser.find_element(By.ID, "time-format-select")
open_menu.click()
```